# Magento 2: Cloud project composer install error module-staging-page-builder (2.2.0): Downloading (failed)

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.2, magento2-cloud, composer-install

I have facing error in composer install in cloud project. Issue is facing in module-staging-page-builder module Downloading (failed).

**Command**

> composer install

**Error:**

> - Installing magento/module-staging-page-builder (2.2.0): Downloading (failed)
>   [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
>   The
>   "https://repo.magento.com/archives/magento/module-staging-page-builder/magento-module-staging-page-builder-2.2.0.0.zip" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1      404 Not Found)
>   install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev]
>   [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts]
>   [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose]
>   [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative]
>   [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] []...

I have added public key and private key in auth.json but not works.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Clear the composer cache and try. Also, check the license expired related issue.

Comment: @SohelRana I have checked not working.

Comment: Do you get the error only for that module? Did you double-check if the correct Adobe Commerce composer auth keys are applied? Do you have an active entitlement for your project?

Comment: I get the exact same error. Help!

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith
Add correct enterprise edition `public key` and `private key` in `auth.json` and run command `composer update` working fine.

Answer (score 0):

**You may check this out. I found it helpful.**

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-knowledge-base/kb/troubleshooting/deployment/magento-commerce-cloud-repo-could-not-be-accessed-403-forbidden-or-404-not-found-error-when-deploying.html?lang=en